# "Roll" vs. "roll up"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

Are these two verbs the same? According to Longman, they are the same.

Here are some made up sentences:

> I rolled this (up) into a ball.
>   Let's roll (up) our sleeves.

(I made up these sentences just to ask if they could mean the same.)

Comment: "Are they the same?" and "Could they mean the same?" are two different questions. Most often (like in this case), the answer to the first question is, "No, not always – only in certain contexts," and the answer to the second question is, "Yes, in certain contexts." By the way, I think it's worth pointing out that this question probably would have been a better fit at the English Language Learners Stack Exchange; you may want to [check it out](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Let's roll up our sleeves." is correct. Without 'up', it sounds wrong, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

In the examples you gave, both "roll" and "roll up" mean the same thing. However, there is a difference between the two verbs. To "[roll](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll)" can mean many things but the only senses that are synonyms with "roll up" are "to form into a mass by turning over and over" and "to wrap round on itself or shape into a ball or roll". To "[roll up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll%20up)" can also mean "to become larger by successive accumulations", among other things that "roll" alone doesn't mean.

Comment: "Roll up! Roll up! See the amazing strength of The Amazing Strongo! All the fun of the fair!"

Comment: Furthermore you can *roll down* your window (or your sleeves).

Comment: Stop, drop, and roll!

Answer (score -1):

They mean the same in that things are being rolled up, but in different ways. 
Rolling up sleeves means to uncover more skin, and to roll something up into a ball means to do something like crumpling a piece of paper up before throwing it out.